# Count passed logins and failed logins in same query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query that select the top 5 of the UID that most logged in.
I show results like that:
"A name" connected 457 times, failed 124 times

My actual query only get the " 457 " times, I don't know how to select the failed logins in the same query.
I have a field in my database named " passed ". The value is 0 if failed, 1 if correct.

Current query:

```
SELECT uid, COUNT(uid) AS cnt
FROM logins
GROUP BY uid
ORDER BY cnt DESC 
LIMIT 5
```

Database structure:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `logins` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `uid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `username` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `ip` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `time` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `passed` int(1) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1544 ;
```

Could you please help me to get working that out?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you show the structure of your table?

Comment: Where do you hold the failed attempts (unpassed logins, as you call it)?

Comment: Yeah sorry I forgot that. I edited the question. I have a field in my database named " passed ". The value is 0 if unpassed, 1 if passed.

Comment: @Shef I edited the question to change unpassed by failed... my english is kinda bad as I'm not a native english speaker. Thanks for the correction.

Comment: And you want 5 users with most passed logins, along with it, you want to count their unpassed logins, right?

Comment: @Shef Exactly, however nobody gived me the perfect query!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT uid, COUNT(uid) AS cnt, COUNT( IF( passed = 0, 1, NULL ) ) AS failed
FROM logins
GROUP BY uid
ORDER BY cnt DESC 
LIMIT 5
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed, no need to re-select. Great job, thanks. I didn't know " IF " statement exists in MySQL, very useful!

Comment: +1. There you go, if OP wants only the users ordered by the successful logins.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT uid, COUNT(uid) AS cnt, (SELECT COUNT(uid) FROM logins WHERE passed=0) AS failed ...
```

You can use an inner select statement to achieve this.